# Fedora 18 not working on an HP Dv7

Tags: fedora, windows, dual-boot, uefi

I've recently installed Fedora 18 on my brand new HP Dv7 that comes with Windows 8 and secure boot. Before install Fedora I disabled secure boot in the BIOS. I've installed Fedora 18 and all is working well, but for some reason the laptop boots to the default bootloader (the HP one that sends you straight to Windows 8) instead of Grub. At boot, I can push F9 and I see

- OS Bootloader - This is the HP Bootloader for windows 8
- Fedora (Hitachi hard drive name) - This is the Grub bootloader
- Select an EFI File -

  In Grub, Fedora and Windows boot just fine, but I want the computer to boot to grub, instead of the HP bootloader, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggested reading: [Rod's books](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/principles.html) on the topic (don't worry, it's concise with good brief-to-readable ratio).

Other than that, try running `efibootmgr` in any EFI-booted Linux distribution.
<sub>(I'd suggest [ALT Linux based rescue](http://en.altlinux.org/Regular#non-desktop) of my make as a shameless plug though)</sub>

If it *does* include a numbered line for Fedora then maybe it's a question to HP support regarding their bootloader compliance; if it does *not* then mount --bind the things needed (including /boot/efi, /proc, /sys and /dev) into fedora's root, `chroot` there and run `grub-install` with no arguments.

There's a couple of workarounds but let's first learn and check the basics.